# Starting external software's setup from flash in windows 7 problem

Tags: flash, windows-7, installation, launch

We have an interactive software created in flash, which starts with a menu with some buttons. To view all content, the user needs the Smart Viewer software. So there is a button in the menu which launches the setup for smart viewer. The problem is that under Windows 7 nothing happens, while under windows xp it works flawless. So basicallly the problem is that the setup won't start if we try to invoke it through flash. Could this be some sort of security problem in windows 7? Any ideas are welcome, thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you launching the setup?

Comment: Sorry, i was busy i couldn't check back and i admit the question was lacking details. The flash used fscommand and i managed to get it going through a proxy. See the answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it using the technique on the following page. The problem lied in the new Vista/Win 7 security.

http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/08/07/Conquering-FSCommand-EXEC-Part-1-Proxy